# Is there a way to run a Firebird stored procedure at specific time?

Tags: firebird

Is there a way to run a Firebird stored procedure at specific time from the server itself ? something like a schedule task service in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin scheduler in Firebird. But it should be relatively easy to set up a task in system scheduler which uses `isql` to execute an sql script which does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible internally. You should use a third party tool.

Please take a look at this [issue](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-743)