# Delete a record after a period of time automatically in SQL Firebird 2.5?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

We have a table which has Datetime stamp field when that record was created. How can we create a trigger or procedure to delete a record after 30 days?

Is there any advice how we can run this deletion scheduler?

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to run a Firebird stored procedure at specific time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428016/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-firebird-stored-procedure-at-specific-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird doesn't have a scheduler. You will need to create an application that executes a clean up routine on a schedule yourself. You could do this as part of the normal application, or you could write a small application specifically for this purpose, and execute it with the scheduler of your OS (e.g. Windows Scheduled Tasks, or Linux Cron).

Answer (score 2):

Firebird 2.1 introduced global `trigger`s fired on database connection/disconnection and on transaction starting/ending.

https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-ddl-trigger.html

While it is not exactly what you need it can be used to achieve similar results. Whether that similarity is good enough for you or not is for you to evaluate.

> to delete a record after 30 days?

The question here is what you do specifically mean here. Would it still be okay, if the row is deleted in 31 day, in 40 days?

In our case, for a client-server office application, there was no time pressure and additionally there was no safe deletion as long as the programs had "documents" open.

We had to delete some global data, and while there were some marks in the database, which documents use them and which documents are currently opened - it was not very reliable. Which also meant that existing method of immediate delete occasionally could lead to application crashes.

So we reformulated a problem similar to yours the following way:

1. We need rows not deleted immediately but pending for deletion for *30 days **or more***.  Those record would be rendered in the application in a special way, as a warning to users and also providing a way for them to cancel deletion, if they changed their mind (or if other users had different ideas).
2. The deletion would happen, in logic terms, "when there is no connected application". In technical term it could mean either "when first application is connecting, but before it started actual (business-related) work" or "when last application is disconnecting, after it ended doing actual work". We settled on the latter, we used `on disconnect` global database trigger.
3. We had not only main business-domain application, but a number of technical helper utilities. From the Firebird point of view there is no difference in them. So we had to modify "login sequence" in our main application: right after successful login it registered it's own `CURRENT_CONNECTION` into a special table. This is potentially slightly fragile.
4. `ON DISCONNECT` trigger used to do three actions:

   - it checked, if `current_connection` is in the table, and if it was - it called a special stored procedure, `SP_LOCAL_CLEANUP`.
   - it removed the `current_connection` from the table (it could had been `BEFORE DELETE` trigger then to call the procedure, but we decided our *helper utilities* should have a way to hook in, if they would need, so the call was put in the `ON DISCONNECT` trigger).
   - it checked if that table (known connected business-domain applications list) became empty, and if it did - called another special stored procedure, `SP_GLOBAL_CLEANUP`.
5. Those stored procedures were "umbrella" procedures, solely consisted of calls to different procedures, which did the actual work of checking for inconsistencies and fixing them. Like, removing marks "this document is opened for editing" if an application (or computer, or network) has crashed without removing the lock normal way. This way we could add or remove functionality without breaking Firebird object dependency chains.
6. In particular, one of the global sub-procedures looked into the "deletion pending" records, and deleted those "kept in recycle bin" for a time span running over 30 days. *Actually, the records just had a column of planned deletion date and that could be more or less than 30 days, but that is technicality.*
7. This meant that the actual deletion was happening "sometimes after 30 days" and it only happened when all main apps were shut down. When later those apps would be run again - they would re-read those global dictionaries tables in the updated, pruned state. The applications never again were in inconsistent state, using records removed from the database.
8. Potential fragile point: if users would not shut down application in the night, but just go home, it could mean there would never be a state "last application disconnected". This, however, would be a maintenance nightmare for their network admins (Windows updates and reboots, antivirus updates and reboots), so we documented the recommendation that those admins have to make sure at least once a week all the users went all together out of the database.
9. Potential fragile point: if the Firebird server crashes (not applications, but the server engine), then the "known connections" table would have stale values. We considered it not a practical problems, as then `CURRENT_CONNECTION` would be restarted as 1 value and go upward, eventually cleaning the table. But we also added a function into helper app, to use `SYSDBA` and monitoring tables and clean the table off non-existing connections.

You can re-use this framework if you do not have time pressure and you are okay if the actual deletion is deferred for a few days.

You can also use `ON TRANSACTION START` trigger instead, to shorten the delay to mere minutes, but I expect this would slow down your application badly, so would suggest against it.

Comment: So much good stuff thanks a lot. We are currently developing an scheduler.

Comment: @TonathiuRedrovan there already was one, but i feel the house is abandoned now - https://www.xstarter.com/rus/firebird-interbase-job-scheduler.php - maybe in some dark internet corners it still can be found. Also - https://firebirdfaq.org/faq141/

Comment: Windows and Linux have built-in scheduler, so the simplest thing might be just calling ISQL command to call some stored procedure, by OS means. Log and error checks then can be offloaded to the main application.